# Receive file using ftp task with filename renamed in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ftp

I am trying to set up an FTP task in SSIS. The source is not variable. The destination folder is predefined. However, I need the received file to be renamed.

LDAP.txt after fetching needs to be LDAP_20140204.txt in my target folder. on using variables, it throws the error

```
'Directory is not specified in the file connection manager'
```

Any work around for this?

Comment: It is possible to use an additional file operation step and use 'Move file' to sort this problem. But can't it be handled within the ftptask itself?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the File System Task?  This will allow you to rename a file.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140185.aspx